# Customise exported CSV content of Sonata Admin bundle

Tags: symfony, csv, export, sonata-admin

I'm new to sonata admin bundle. Now, I am try to export a csv file with something like: 'customer.phone', 'order.total'... but when I opened the csv file, in the field 'order.total' is only '99.99', I would like it to export as 'AUD $99.99', anyone know how I can achieve it? Thank a lot! The code is here:

```
public function getExportFields() {
    return array('id','customer.First_name','customer.Last_name',
        'customer.contact','total_amount'
        );
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to define method `getTotalAmountFormated` in your `Order` class, and make it return string that you need. Then add `totalAmountFormated` (or `total_amount_formated`, I think both should work) in array returned from `getExportFields`

```
public function getExportFields() {
    return array('id','customer.First_name','customer.Last_name',
        'customer.contact','totalAmountFormated'
        );
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply @tiriana. That is right, but I found that I'm not sure how to retrieve the value of 'total_amount' from this format, in other words, I'm not sure how to get the order object and get order.getTotal() to store the value, I've tried this->getSubject() something like that, but return exception of none object error.

Comment: Take a look at my update. You cannot use getSubject in exportAction, because it doesn't operate on single instance, but on list, a collection. So getSubject returns null in export. Insted of that you need to inform admin what property it should look for while iterating throught that collection. And if you are not falimiar with property_path I suggest you take a look at PropertyAcces component http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html#usage

Comment: Got what you mean. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add, you can customize the header of each column like such:

```
public function getExportFields() {
    return array(
      'Id' => 'id',
      'Customer First Name' => 'customer.First_name',
      'Customer Last Name' => 'customer.Last_name',
      'Customer Contact' => 'customer.contact',
      'Total Amount' => 'totalAmountFormated'
    );
}
```